# Debezium MongoDb - adding non metadata headers with ExtractNewDocumentState SMT not working

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm having trouble adding an header from a document field (not metadata), which I'm able to do using the ExtractNewRecordState SMT on Postgres, but not using ExtractNewDocumentState on MongoDb.

This is the configuration which allows me to copy a non metadata field to a header using ExtractNewRecordState (by reaching into the "after" object):

```
"transforms": "unwrap",
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
"transforms.unwrap.add.headers": "after.Id:Id",
"transforms.unwrap.add.headers.prefix": "",
```

If I try the same configuration using the ExtractNewDocumentState SMT for MongoDb, it doesn't work:

```
"transforms": "unwrap",
"transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState",
"transforms.unwrap.add.headers": "after.Id:Id",
"transforms.unwrap.add.headers.prefix": "",
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected field name: after.Id
```

I suspect it has to with the type of the "after" object being a string, instead of an object (as in Postgres), so at this point the SMT is not able to reach into the object to get the fields.

From what I've seen there is no SMT available for copying a field into a header, so how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "`after` is a string"? If you want an object, you need to change your converter classes. However, not many transforms can access nested fields anyway. Also the transform itself extracts/flattens the `after` field, so have you tried just using `Id:Id`?

Comment: Using "Id:Id" results in the following error "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Id:Id is not a valid field name".
What i meant regarding the after field is that using the MongoDB connector the content of the after field is a string, which holds the json payload of the object. With the Postgres connector, the content is an object, which is what leads me to believe that this might be the cause of the problem, since the usage of "add.headers" I mentioned in my question works with the Postgres connector, but not the MongoDb one.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Debezium, not the official Mongo connector. If you look at the docs, the transform you're using is supposed to remove the after field https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html  Regarding objects, you've not specified what converters you're using

Comment: The ExtractNewDocumentState transform does remove the after field after it finishes. The problem is the "add.headers" config does not allow me to add headers from the after object, such as i'm able to do with the ExtractNewRecordState transform in Postgres. Also, I'm using the AvroConverter.

Comment: So, what all have you tried? `after.Id:Id` and `Id:Id` don't work... I cannot find the docs that say the colons are supported, so what about `after.Id` or just `Id`? However, if the data is just a Avro-encoded string and not an Avro Struct of key-value pairs, then fields cannot be referenced, anyway